# Centering a search field inside a flex container while keeping a logo to the right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to center a search field (using flex box) inside a toolbar so that it aligns perfectly with cards contained inside a container below the toolbar.

The yellow search field should be align with the orange cards below it.

The logo is supposed to be self aligned to the left and the menu should be self aligned to the right.  I thought `justify-self: start | end` would do this ...

This is a demo:

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.Toolbar {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.Logo {
  justify-self: start;
  margin-left:10px;
  width: 40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.SearchField 
{
  justify-self:center;
  width: 200px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Menu {
  justify-self: end;
  width: 40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.Card {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: orange;
}

.CardContainer {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<div class="Toolbar">
  <div class="Logo">
    Logo
  </div>  
  <div class="SearchField">
    Search Field
  </div>  
  <div class="Menu">
    Menu
  </div>  
</div>
<main>
<div class="CardContainer">
  <div class="Card">
  </div>
  <div class="Card">
  </div>  
</div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as close as you're gonna get it.
By the way, you can only use `align-self` in flex children, there is no `justify-self`.

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.Toolbar {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.Logo {
  width: 40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.SearchField 
{
  width: 200px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.Menu {
  width: 40px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.Card {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: orange;
}

.CardContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div class="Toolbar">
      <div class="Logo">
        Logo
      </div>  
      <div class="SearchField">
        Search Field
      </div>  
      <div class="Menu">
        Menu
      </div>  
    </div>
    <main>
    <div class="CardContainer">
      <div class="Card">
      </div>
      <div class="Card">
      </div>  
    </div>
    </main>
</div>
```